# Highcharts Legend event click to get data

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, scatter-plot

I am working on a Scatterplot + Plot lines chart, which has multiple legends. I have to change the value of the plot lines based on the scatterplot values. Could anyone help me out in getting the scatter plot value once I click on any legend items?

I have done this code, Which gives me an alert when I click on any legend. Next, I have to get the scatterplot value and change the plot line graph

```
 events: {
                legendItemClick: function(e) {
                    if(this.visible) {

                        alert('visible');


                    }
                    else {
                         console.log("result"+result);
                        alert('Not visible');

                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo? It looks like a part of it, which does not allow us to reproduce the case.

Comment: You can update the series data with dynamic methods such as series.update() or [series.setData()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData). You can get the series by its id http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.get and extract its from the series.data array - see the example http://jsfiddle.net/8ce0euyg/

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar but for series Plot, but this will surely give you the approach you need to adopt.

```
if(series.name=='xyz'){//you can handle multiple legends by checking their name and have different calls for different legends

                    if (!this.visible) {// i want to make request for data only if when i click the legend and its visible 
                    $.getJSON('xyzdata.php',{parameter1:xyz1,parameter2:xyz2}, function(data) {// making the call 
                        series.setData(data.a);// with the returned data defining my plot
                        series.xAxis.setCategories(data.b);
                    });

 };
```

Hope that helps!